# What's wrong with using protium catalytically in a fusion reactor?

Tags: fusion

P-D fusion results in 3He, then D-3He results in a P+D+D turning into P+4He. Isn't that net energy positive at a relatively low temperature without too many neutrons? Some D+D side products will happen but if my reading of rates is right then there's a temperature range where D-3He will happen a lot more and the D-D reaction will release neutrons which want to take energy out of the core and having 3He in there to act as a neutron poison will make it produce more energy and keep the heat inside. The obvious potential pitfalls are if P-D allows too much energy to escape as a gamma ray or neutrino or if D-D happens at a fast rate at a lower temperature than D-3He.

Comment: What are the cross sections vs energy for the various reactions? Under what conditions? Just throwing out reactions is not all you need to know.

Comment: Going off the [Wikipedia fusion page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fusion) the rates and cross section of D-3He is basically always favorable over D-D and it produces quite a lot of energy even accounting for losses, although not as favorable as D-T. Those charts don't include info on P-D, but that happens at a much lower temperature in the sun. The idea here is to avoid needing either T or 3He as fuel.

Comment: Reactions in the sun is not a useful measure without a ~sun sized reactor. P-D fusion is not on the graphs ( such as https://www.mdpi.com/1420-3049/19/10/17052/htm) for a reason - the cross section is small (compare with P-T where you know He-4 is very favorable energetically).

Comment: I've been assuming that the p-D cross section is high because the sources say that deuterium only lasts a few seconds in the sun before getting fused, for example [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160620155744/http://csep10.phys.utk.edu/astr162/lect/energy/ppchain.html) says it's 1 second and [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction) says its 4 seconds even with 3He-3He taking a million years at these low temperatures. My assumption is that the real issue is that p-D is endothermic by itself.